# Boost FileSystem v3 append failed with char array

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems, boost-filesystem

I have the error below with boost 1.53, but do not have it with 1.56.

```
../../source/EntryPoint/Application.cpp:100:58: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::filesystem::path::append(const char [22])’
 petscConfigurationPath.append("FluidPetsc/Basic.conf");
```

**Notes:**
The question is why I can append array of chars to boost::filesystem::path in version 1.56 and I cannot in version 1.53?

Answer (score 1):

In older versions you to get a `std::string` (which has `append` that takes a literal), but now you have a `path`, so you can't just `append` directly on it.

---

You didn't show the code, but some API's have changed: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/v3.html.

In particular,

> - Certain functions now return path objects rather than  string or wstring 
>     objects:
>
>   - root_name()
>   - root_directory()
>   - filename()
>   - stem()
>   - extension()

Note that the deprecated "v2" APIs have been around for long, but got cut in some later version :

> To ease the transition, Boost releases 1.44 through 1.47 will supply both V2 and V3. Version 2 is the default version for Boost release 1.44 and 1.45. Version 3 will be the default starting with release 1.46.

Comment: I am sorry I dont undestand the first part of your answer. Could you paraphrase/correct/clarify?

Comment: @user14416 Erm... ***You*** should  clarify. I've explained _exactly_ why the code is not compiling using all the evidence you post in your question. Because the rest is not given, I'm helpful in pointing you to assorted bits of the relevant documentation regarding breaking API changes. You can either figure it out from here, or you posts a MCVE or SSCCE sample.

Comment: "In older versions you to get a std::string" --- can you paraphrase this part I dont understand it. "but now you have a path, so you can't just append directly on it." --- what do you mean I cannot append directly, append what to what, on what? Clarify plzz.

Comment: What code do you want to see? The whole code is there (`petscConfigurationPath.append("FluidPetsc/Basic.conf");`)

Comment: See the update if it will help you to understand the question.

Comment: What can we say. It seems obvious you're seeing a breaking change (otherwise you couldn't compile the same code v1.53). You still don't show any part of the related code, so we can't see more. What's the type of `petscConfigurationPath`? Is it `const`? Why is the overload being rejected? (What is the rest of the compiler message) etc. Maybe you can use `operator/=`, although that would be the 'blind' way to resolve it. I'd prefer to understand what's happening and why. (This is better because it will empower you to analyze similar challenges in the future)